# Tips For Freelancing & Wordpress Workflow

Tags: attracting-clients, web-development, portfolio

Im looking to start freelancing using Wordpress. However I would love some advice on my workflow. It's my first time doing this, so Im sure its lacking.

What my plan is so far:

1) Send email to potential clients giving them a offer

2) If they respond and want my help with their website, then I ask what they want and we agree on what it will cost etc.

3) Then I will send a contract for them to sign. I will have them pay me 30-40% of the total cost up front.

4) Once all of that is done I will make wireframes, sketches and prototypes etc. I will send it over to them to make sure they like it.

5) After that I will setup a git repository and start developing the site locally.

6) During the process I will occasionally show them what has been done.

7) Once I've made what we agreed on I will transfer the site to either their host or offer them hosting on my reseller account.

8) I'll have them pay the rest and make sure they are aware that I'm willing to keep helping them with the site if they pay for it.

Now my question is - how can I improve this?

Also a second question: On my portfolio website I currently have two projects. One of them being a website for my mothers business, however her domain is very similar to mine, so its obvious that we are related. Is it weird to use family projects in your portfolio? Does that in any way tell the potential clients that I cant get real clients/my work isn't attractive? Or should I let it stay to show my work?

Any help on any of the steps or just freelancing/web development tips in general is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your plan sounds good so far; I would recommend that you expand on your plans for showing them the site, and maybe offer them the opportunity to QA it a bit to make sure it's exactly what they want.

It's hard to say on your mother's website; it may raise some eyebrows that you don't have much else to show, but if it's all you have, it's better than nothing, and it will still give a good idea of your work!

I also recommend that you check out this site; it is specifically and only for freelance developers, and they also offer a great free guide to use in starting out:

https://subspace.net/guide-to-freelancing

Good luck!